# PostgreSQL Query To Group IP Integer Values By Subnet In A List

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table of the following:

```
ip         | value
2379284488 | 2
2379284482 | 4
3226028805 | 3
```

And I have a list of two integers, 3226028800 and 2379284480, I would like to create a query with an output similar to this:

```
net        | ip         | value
2379284480 | 2379284488 | 2
2379284480 | 2379284482 | 4
3226028805 | 3226028805 | 3
```

Where `net & ip = net`. What is the simplist way to do this within a single query in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Why don’t you store ip addresses as an inet data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply join them like code below:

```
WITH subnet_list AS (
    SELECT unnest(ARRAY[3226028800, 2379284480]) AS subnet
)
SELECT 
    SL.subnet AS net,
    ip_table.ip,
    ip_table.value
FROM
    subnet_list SL
JOIN 
    ip_table ON (ip_table.ip & SL.subnet) = SL.subnet;
```

Here is [sample fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/7cbUjXq6)